# Querying lucene index with arbitrary long article text to check for all matches within article (through neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, lucene, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm trying to query the lucene index I've added to a neo4j field (it's a "name" field, that isn't very long, one to ten words at most).

What I do right now is take all the text in a given webpage, sanitize it with a javascript function to keep only words, spaces and alphanumeric characters, and use that to query my index.

```
.replace(/[^\w\s]|or|and|not|return+/gi, "") // <- escaping the input
```

I'm not sure if the length of the search text is limited somehow, but results do seem to disappear after about 1050 words (~6500 characters).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use a couple thousand words in one query, with the end goal of highlighting the matches found within the webpage itself.

Why is my query not returning any results past a certain number of characters ? Am I missing some keyword in my escaping regex ?

Is what I'm trying to achieve feasible ? Is there a better approach I could use ?

Thanks for reading :)

(for anyone finding this, I found a somewhat related question here: [Handling large search queries on relatively small index documents in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219657/handling-large-search-queries-on-relatively-small-index-documents-in-lucene))